# Manual Webhook trigger and "webhook.create"

Tags: podio

1. Is it possible to trigger **specific** webhooks using the API?

We programmatically create Webhooks on all target Apps and want those hooks to be triggered once after the installation. We though of adding a tag and removing it right away (or modifying any field and putting it back right away), but this would trigger other `item.update` Webhooks as well.

2. When a Webhook is created or deleted, is the Webhook `app.update` launched?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Only by performing the same types of actions that will normally fire a webhook. I.e. you cannot fake it.
2. No, the app.update webhook is only fired when the app is saved through the template editor.

Comment: Does adding a tag trigger the `item.update` webhook?

Comment: I believe it's only actual fields, but try it out. Should be easy to test

Comment: To add the info on here, the webhook is not triggered upon adding a tag.

Comment: To conclude, the workaround (not clean...) that avoids any issues is to create a custom field through the API, add a value in it and then delete that field.